# Quality must range from 0 to 100 image intervention laravel 8

Tags: image-processing, file-upload, laravel-8, image-resizing

i am facing this issue while resizing image.

```
$brand_image=$request->file('brand_image');
     $img_name=time().$brand_image->getClientOriginalName();
       

       $img=Image::make($brand_image)->resize(30,20);

        $img->save('images/brands/',$img_name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$img->save('images/brands/'.$img_name);
```

with dot (`.`) for concatenation not comma (`,`)

I solved it in my case:

```
Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save('upload/brands/'.$name_gen);
```